# Downloading and installing from App Store would fail?

Tags: ios, app-store, installation

I just release a new version of my app. But unfortunately the new version app crashes every time it launches.

So I used a file tool, which could browse, copy and export files inside iPhone, to export the .ipa file of my app that crash.

Then I find the archive that submitted to App Store by Xcode, extract an .ipa file from the archive. And if I install the ipa file with the tool I used, it would launch and work properly.

After I got 2 ipa files, I unzip them and use some file merge tool to check the difference between folders and files in that two ipa files, finding that the failed one seemed not to be updated. Some new-added file didn't exist and some renamed file didn't change their names.

### So I doubt if the process of downloading and installing app from App Store go wrong, though it sounds like impossible.

There is part of crash log on my device. But I can barely read useful information from it.

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGILL)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x000000000000b6d2
Highlighted Thread:  1

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39a71648 kevent64 + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x399aa4ec _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 792
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x3999cdf4 _dispatch_mgr_thread$VARIANT$up + 32

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39a81d98 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x399cfcf6 _pthread_workq_return + 14
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x399cfa12 _pthread_wqthread + 362
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x399cf8a0 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39a81d98 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x399cfcf6 _pthread_workq_return + 14
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x399cfa12 _pthread_wqthread + 362
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x399cf8a0 start_wqthread + 4

Unknown thread crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0x0006c0f8    r1: 0x2fda1cd4      r2: 0x0006bfd4      r3: 0x2fda1d08
    r4: 0x2ff0214c    r5: 0x2ff020ec      r6: 0x0006bebd      r7: 0x0000002f
    r8: 0x2ff046ac    r9: 0x0000ab00     r10: 0x00000000     r11: 0x00000049
    ip: 0x1f507620    sp: 0x2fda0a20      lr: 0x2feee51d      pc: 0x0006be88
  cpsr: 0x80000030
```

Need help. Thanks for reading.

Comment: There is no useful information here. My best guess would be that you mistakenly submitted an old archive.

Comment: Thank you @RanDahan. But I am sure the archive is good. I found the archive through Xcode -- Organizer -- Archive -- Reveal in Finder, made an ipa and installed it on my device. And my app works.